# Correct way to pass a set of images to a model for training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a Keras model to train with a group of images, taken from a list of paths.
I know that the method `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` exists but it doesn't meet my needs because I want to learn the correct way to handle images and because I need to make a regression, not a classification.
Every approach I tried failed one way or another, mostly because the type of the x_train variable is wrong.

The most promising function I used to load a single image is:

```
def encode_image(img_path):
  img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path)
  img_array = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
  img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
  return img_array

x_train = df['filename'].apply(lambda i: encode_image(i))
```

This doesn't work because, when I call the .fit() method this way:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
```

I receive the following error:

```
Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)
```

This makes me understand that I'm passing the data in a wrong format.
Can someone provide me a **basic example** of creating a (x_train, y_train) pair to feed a model for training using a set of images?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

The Numpy error can be fixed using the **tf.convert_to_tensor()** method.

```
img_array = tf.convert_to_tensor(img_array)
```

The code you requested for reference for working of images is as follows :

```
import tensorflow as tf
# Load the training and test split of the Fashion MNIST dataset
(training_images, training_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fmnist.load_data()

# Normalize the pixel values of the train and test images
training_images  = training_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

# Build the classification model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

# Declare sample inputs and convert to a tensor
inputs = np.array([[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 2.0]])
inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(inputs)
print(f'input to softmax function: {inputs.numpy()}')

# Feed the inputs to a softmax activation function
outputs = tf.keras.activations.softmax(inputs)
print(f'output of softmax function: {outputs.numpy()}')

prediction = np.argmax(outputs)
print(f'class with highest probability: {prediction}')

model.compile(optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)

# Evaluate the model on unseen data
model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)
```

Hope this solves your query.